# Android: open an external project with Android Studio

Tags: android

I am a really unexperienced Android programmer, so apologies if the question is trivial. I am trying to open a sample that I download from this page: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html (on the right side). This zip file just contains a res and src folder and the AndroidManifest.
Could anyone tell me how to open it on Android Studio? It is something SO trivial but I am not being able to do it! I am on Windows 7 64bit.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio

file->import project

Navigate to the directory that contains the android.xml. Should be the top level directory of your unzipped sample.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio v1.0+ allows importing samples directly from Google:

File > Import sample...

Answer (score 0):

in `Android Studio` try

`File` > `New` > `Import Project`

or you can create a new project and replace the folders `/res`, `/src` and the `AndroidManifest.xml` (personally prefer the first option)